# How to mark a certain cell as edited by traversing through an object that contains the info if edited or not in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am trying to write a simple CSS for a cell in a table by marking it as `edited` when clicked. The information is stored in an array of objects, but only the array element whose edited object is `true` can be marked as `edited`.

Here is a sample code for the table content:

```js
const getTbl = [
  {
    key: "custNo",
    label: "Customer",
    className: isCustEdited ? "normalCSS editedCSS" : "normalCSS",
    formatter: (item) => {
      return (
        <TextInput
          id={item.item.id}
          value={item.item.value}
        />
      );
    }
  }
];
```

I have set the `isCustEdited` to a boolean value in a `useEffect` every time the table is updated, ie. any entries, clicks, etc. But since I need cell-level CSS for only individual cells and not the entire column, the above approach doesn't work. Also, I have to write the CSS at the cell level and not for the `TextInput` component as there is a lot of other conflicting CSS. I was thinking about linking the `id` of the edited customer with the CSS but I have no clue how to do so. Or maybe even creating an array of objects and setting only the ones marked as `true` as `edited`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide us with the rest of the code like what the click function is, the hook itself, the react component. There is nothig much to give advices on yet.